# PCA - Clustering when more than 2 PCs

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, pca

I have performed a PCA and my top 2 PCs only give 50% variation, I want to include 8 PCs. How would I visualise this in clusters on a single plot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pairplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) method of [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) library. 
For example the iris dataset could be plot as:
[image]

In this way you can analyze the relationship between species for all characteristic combinations.